# select single or multiple records using a single linq query

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework, drop-down-menu

I want to pass a valid  id or -1("ALL")  from a drop down to the function.
 Can I select 'All' rows  or one row based on the selected option from ddl from a table using a single linq query?

Comment: post your query so we can update it

Answer (score 0):

You can add an OR to the statement to get the result.  Basically, (@value = -1) OR (id = @value).  Whenever value is -1, it will return all value, otherwise that we be false and only return the matching record.

Answer (score 0):

Having an OR in the LINQ can sometimes result in full-table scans and non-optimal retrievals.

Instead of having a condition inside your LINQ statement, I'd recommend building your LINQ query conditionally based on whether you want a single result or "all":

```
// Initialize your select
var query = db.Select(r => r);

// Conditionally add the "where"
if (selectedValue != -1)
  query = query.Where(n => n.id == selectedValue);

// Collect your results
foreach (var record in query)
{
  // ...
}
```

If you want all records, then your query won't include a where clause at all, otherwise, the where clause will include only the filter by id.